# Where to find the most visited websites by state

Tags: search, visitors

Is there a service (free or paid) that can provide the following:
1. List of most visited websites by U.S. state.
2. Keyword search in google by U.S. state.

Answer (score 2):

In short, no, [Nielsen Web Rankings](http://www.nielsen-online.com/resources.jsp?section=pr_netv) will give you the most detailed summary of websites across the us/world/etc but it's based on a data collection augmented with statistical modelling.

As for keywords you're best off with [Google Insights for search](http://www.google.com/insights/search/) and [Google Trends](http://www.google.com/trends/) but I don't think these will breakdown by state.

Most paid analytics companies offer benchmarking tools which allow you to compare your website with others in the sector *that they have data for* Google analytics does this for free and is likely to have more data than anyone else.